# Información de un objeto en un modal, de forma ordenada

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, modal

Estoy haciendo un programa para ventas y tengo un listado con todas las ventas y a quien le corresponde esa venta. La idea es que cuando hago click en el nombre de la persona, me aparezca un modal con otro listado donde pueda ver todas las ventas de esa persona. Eso lo logré hacer funcionar, en el modal me aparecen correctamente todas las ventas de esa determinada persona. El tema es que no logro encontrar otra manera de que me aparezcan los datos de forma ordenada, ya que utilicé la función *.inspect*.
Agradecería mucho su ayuda en este problema. Desde ya, muchas gracias. Aquí les dejo el código del modal.

```
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Compras cliente</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body" id="customer_sales_data">
        <%= Sale.where(:account_id => account_id).inspect %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tu debes dar el formato/orden que deseas a la información que obtienes a partir de `Sale.where(:account_id => account_id)`.

Por ejemplo, suponiendo que cada registro de `Sale` tiene una fecha (`date`) y un monto (`amount`), harías algo así:

```
<div class="modal-body" id="customer_sales_data">
  <% Sale.where(:account_id => account_id).each do |sale| %>
    <p><%= sale.date %> - <%= sale.amount %></p>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Con el código anterior, pondrás una nueva línea (con tag `p`) para cada registro en `Sale`. El formato puede ser el que quieres (divs anidados, tablas, etc), siempre que sea html válido.

---

Como mejora, te recomendaría mover el código `Sale.where(:account_id => account_id)` al controlador; generalmente es mala práctica llevar a cabo ese tipo de consultas dentro de una vista.

Algo simialar a:

```
class SalesController
  def modal
    @sales = Sale.where(account_id: prams[:account_id])
  end
end
```

Y en tu vista:

```
<div class="modal-body" id="customer_sales_data">
  <% @sales.each do |sale| %>
    <p><%= sale.date %> - <%= sale.amount %></p>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que entiendo, la respuesta a tu duda está en: [Order Method](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-order)

Si aplicamos lo que dice en la pagina de la API de ROR (el enlace que acabo de compartirte), y suponiendo que el campo por el cual ordenas las ventas del vendedor se llame "fecha", yo haría lo siguiente:

```
class SalesController
  def modal
    @sales = Sale.where(account_id: prams[:account_id]).order(:fecha)
  end
end
```